# Hangman method with Swing

Tags: java, swing, methods, textfield

I have all of the necessary instance variables and all of the other classes in place, but I need help figuring out a way to set the user's progress in solving the word's TextField to initially show as many underscores as the letters in the secretWord.
I was thinking something like,

```
//One for each letter
theWordField.setText("" +
    theWordField.getText().replace(
        theWordField.substring((secretWord.indexOf("A")),  
        secretWord.indexOf("A")), _));
```

But you cant use substring in the TextField and I dont know how else to do it

Comment: Do yourself and us a favor and try not to stuff as much code as humanly possible on one line. Instead solve your problem in a step-wise fashion with each small step getting it's own well-deserved line of code. It's in the small details where you'll solve your problem.\

Comment: Consider using an array of char or a StringBuilder object, and then swapping char's as needed.

Comment: There's a couple of issues. The first is that you need to get the text of theWordField first. theWordField.getText().substring solves that problem. But you have more problems than that... If you do as @HovercraftFullOfEels suggest and solve your problem logically 1 step at a time, you can see what parts of this make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of the secret word using:

```
secretWord.length();
```

Once you know the length of the string, you can insert the equivalent number of underscores into the text field by either relying on the previous text inserted already, or creating your own string and adding underscores as such:

```
String textFieldString = "";
for(int i=0; i<secretWord.length(); i++) {
    textFieldString += "_";
}

textField.setText(textFieldString);
```

Answer (score 0):

just load it in a loop

for example:

```
String wordToGuess = "example";
String hidden = "";
for(int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++){
    hidden += "_";
}

theWordField.setText(hidden);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `theWordField.getText().substring()`